# Grails 2, run-war -> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin

Tags: grails, war, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception, grails-2.0

Got a Grails 2 app and executing run-app works fine, run-war fails:

```
2011-12-24 12:43:40,996 [Thread-2] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lgrails/test/mixin/services/ServiceUnitTestMixin;
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lgrails/test/mixin/services/ServiceUnitTestMixin;
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin
    ... 7 more
```

Just run into this problem after having a pretty much flawless experience of working with Grails 2,

How has this come about is a complete headscratcher for me:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lgrails/test/mixin/services/ServiceUnitTestMixin;
```

... any feedback will be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running `grails clean`?

Comment: ... yep, just tried it again now, same error after cleaning.

Comment: Did you try deleting your whole ~/.grails directory (or equivalent on Mac/Windows)? Did you try to delete your target and out directories before run-war?

Comment: ... did both, no effect :-(, this is really troublesome. The whole project just dead in the water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and solved it by doing the following in order:

1. Delete everything in the target directory
2. grails clean
3. grails compile
4. grails run-war

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue and the accepted answer didn't work for me, so I dived a bit closer...

What I found is a class `MyServiceTests` that had somehow managed to sneak out of `grails-app/test/unit/` into `grails-app/services/`; probably during some kind of package rename refactoring. After moving  `MyServiceTests` back to test/unit everything has worked fine again.

Answer (score 1):

The package name of the controller has to match the package name of the domain class. Make sure your package names are consistent throughout the project, including lower and upper case in the package name. Some IDEs are not consistent in updating accidental typos throughout the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation to johanneslink.

The application wouldn't start in Tomcat. Checking catalina.out showed a ClassNotFoundException caused by grails.test.mixin.services.ServiceUnitTestMixin

I used grep to look for all occurrences of 'ServiceUnitTestMixin' in the whole of the application folder (starting in the parent of grails-app). I found that somehow I'd imported grails.test.mixin.Mock into a Controller.

Once I removed that and clean/compiled the war file it deployed and started just fine.